# Mysql query for counting days in some season by date range

Tags: mysql, date, range, case

So, Im trying to make a query that will count how many days belong in different seasons. Its for site that's about booking apartments and it can have multiple seasons one after another. For example:

| Season_id |   From     |   Till     |

|   1    | 2015-09-01 | 2015-09-30 |

|   2    | 2015-09-30 | 2015-10-20 |

|   3    | 2015-10-30 | 2015-12-30 |

So when someone is searching to book for date ex.:

2015-09-25 - 2015-10-10.

I want to get result like:

Seasons:   1, 2

Count days:  5, 10

Is it possible to do that with one query or it must be multiple??

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It'd be a hugely ugly query doing it all-in-one, since you'd have to account for all possible overlaps. e.g. consider a start/end date that covers all THREE seasons. e.g. `start=2015-09-01/end=2015-12-29`. considering a single season only, there's 6 ways your start/end dates can overlap (or not) that season's start/end.

Comment: Oh, and your seasons themselves overlap. so if a booking ends on (say) 2015-09-30. does that count as TWO seasons, since that date is in seasons 1 **AND** 2?

Comment: @MarcB Hi, thanks for quick reply. Well its client request that dates can be overlaping, so when some booking request happens for dates like e.g. **start=2015-09-20/end=2015-09-30** then finish date 2015-09-30 is considered in first season (season id: 1) beacuse that's day when guests are leaving and app counts nights of sleeping. And when someone is coming on 2015-09-30 that's then considering season id: 2 beacuse it will not count day but night from 2015-09-30 to 2015-10-01 as one night.

Comment: I hope I made it clear little bit :D , sorry I'm not good at explaning :).  I need that for calculating price for specific bookings and problem is that I have inherited project from previous programer that put seasons with dates in one table and prices for each season in other table instead in that same table with seasons. So I have to make multiple queries, first for getting all seasons in that date and then getting prices for each season. Its kinda annoying :).